# Type 'string' | null is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, jwt, angular11

I am using angular-jwt to to check whether token is expire or not and while using i am getting this error

> Type 'string' | null is not assignable to type 'string'

```
helper = new JwtHelperService();

var token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');
this.helper.isTokenExpired(token); // this line contains the error
```

> Error

[image]

[image]

Comment: What version of `TypeScript` you are using?

Comment: @slideshowp2 thank you for you response. I am using typescript version ~4.0.2.

Comment: Are you using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@auth0/angular-jwt? What's the version?

Comment: The error is exactly what it means: token can be `null` and it therefore cannot be passed into the argument that does not accept a potential null value. Check if the value is null or not before passing it. Or, if it is null change it’s value to undefined.

Comment: Yes i am using auth0/angular-jwt

Comment: The code in the screenshot doesn't match the code above it. `localStorage.getItem` might return `null` so specifying `string` as the type for `token` would probably cause an error at that point (unless you are not using strict null checks in your tsconfig)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you should check your token

```
    var token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (token) {
       this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe try adding an "if" condition before to check if "token" is not null:

```
var token: string = localStorage.getItem('token');
if (token)
   this.helper.isTokenExpired(token); // this line contains the error
```

Comment: `localStorage.getItem('token')` returns `string|null`, so it will cause typescript error if it is cast to `string`

Answer (score 2):

Your token can't be null. Try

```
let token = localStorage.getItem('token');
token = token === null ? undefined : token;
this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution.

```
let token: any = localStorage.getItem('token');

if (token == null)
  token = undefined;

return this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting this error because your var token can have either string or null value that's why what you should do is provide it a null value as well in option.

like this,

```
helper = new JwtHelperService();

var token: string|null = localStorage.getItem('token');

this.helper.isTokenExpired(token);
```

this might help you
Thanks